# ggplot kernal density plot lines overlapping improperly

Tags: r, ggplot2, stat, kernel-density, density-plot

The colors in my density plot are wrong! I can't figure out why.

Here is my data: https://pastebin.com/0jqHgvxx

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=amountremain, color=black)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

When I check the raw data, I see that the red peak at x=0 is correct but the max x value corresponds to the a y-value for the red not blue line.

The max x value for black = TRUE is 162414.6, max x for black = FALSE is 253021.3 so the tail should be red not blue.

```
b <- unclass(density(data$amountremain[data$black==FALSE]))
max(b$y)
max(b$x)
[1] 0.0003079798
[1] 253021.3
```

```
a <- unclass(density(data$amountremain[data$black==TRUE]))
max(a$y)
max(a$x)
[1] 0.0002832889
[1] 162414.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at a different scale on the y-axis you can see that the last non-zero value of `TRUE` is just about 160000, while the last non-zero value of `FALSE` is about 250000 as it should be.

So the representation is correct but it is difficult to see the tails.

To see:

```r
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=amountremain, color=black)) +
  geom_density() + 
  ylim(0, 10^-5)
```

---

**EDIT**

---

@MrFlick explained why the line doesn't break.
If your goal is to interrupt the distribution of `TRUE` on the last value, one possible solution is to create two distinct density dataframes:

```r
to_dens <- function(df) {
  d <- density(df)
  df_d <- tibble(x = d$x, y = d$y)
  return(df_d)
}

df1 <- df %>% 
  filter(black == TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(to_dens(amountremain))

df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(black == FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(to_dens(amountremain))

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x = x, y = y), col = "steelblue3") +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y), col = "firebrick2")
```

Comment: My concern is that the blue line (TRUE) extends past it's last value of ~160000. Shouldn't the blue line just end there?

Comment: @myfatson In general, densities assumes infinite support. They don't assume they are bounded by the observed min and max values. Therefore when ggplot draws the curve, the curve always extends across the entire visible region.